# AngularJS $resource returns "Load canceled"

Tags: javascript, django, rest, angularjs, single-page-application

I'm making a RESTful single page app using AngularJS and following tutorials this part of the code should work:

```
bosApp.factory('Revision', function($resource, $http) {
    return $resource('http://example.com/api/v1/articlerevision/:id/', {
            id: '@is'
        },
        {
            update: {
                method: 'POST'
                params: {"update": true},
                isArray: false
            },
            save: {
                method: 'PUT'
            },
            query: {
                method: 'GET',
                isArray: true,
                transformResponse: tastypieDataTransformer($http)
            },
            create: {
                method: 'POST'
            }
        }
    );
});

var CreateCtrl = function($scope, $location, Revision) {
    $scope.save = function() {
        Revision.create($scope.revision);
        $location.path('/revision-list');
    };
};
```

and yet it doesn't :) in network tab I get the following issue: method isn't `post` but `options`, status: `load cancelled` and type: `pending` so why is it so and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're seeing `OPTION` instead of `POST`, it likely means you're running into a Cross-Origin-Resource-Sharing limitation.  You're browser is blocking the XHR call because your server isn't configured to allow cross-origin (between different domains) calls.